# Does phpmyadmin's linter has a bug?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, codemirror

I created two tables from phpmyadmin like this

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
place varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
email varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and another one like this

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
menu_name varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
menu_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
date_of_order date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK orders menu_id  customer id_idx` (`menu_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK orders menu_id  customer id` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`)
    REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

after this i insert a value in the first table called 'customers' like this:

[image]

now after that when i insert values into the 'orders' table, phpmyadmin linter displays error like this:

[image]

However, strangely when i click 'Go', the query works fine. It also works fine through the command line too. So is it a bug? or i have to write it in a different way?

Comment: Try to add `;` after each `INSERT`

Comment: Linter still shows error @lad2025 it shows 'Unrecognized statement type. (near VALUES)'

Comment: `INSERT INTO .... VALUES (...);`?

Comment: If i remove the semicolon from  the first then it shows the same error as in the image above and when i add it in both the lines it says Unrecognized statement type and in both cases the query does not get executed

Comment: Try to write complete query in one line and put `;` after every query.

Comment: Even if i do that @Shaharyar linter shows same. Link is here http://imgur.com/dxlI8nW

Comment: It seems a bug in linter not expecting a `SELECT statement` in an `INSERT statement`.

Comment: @Shaharyar any chance updating phpmyadmin to its latest might solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in phpmyadmin sql query parser in [parsing sub queries](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/52). The issue is opened and has not been entertained yet.

You have some alternatives here:

[Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/en/editor/)

Or you can try a different mySql client:

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, phpmyadmin version 4.5.1 had a bug which @Shaharyar mentioned above. i apologize for not posting the version before. However, updating it to version 4.6.3 fixed the issue. Thank you.